# What is the use of $ sign in karate framework?

Tags: karate, cucumber-java, web-api-testing

I've recently started working on Karate and couldn't understand the use of $. example : * def token = $.access_token. Read somewhere that it points the root of the Jsonpath. Can someone please elaborate with examples?

Answer (score 3):

Please read this part of the docs, and also follow the links, there are examples: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-short-cuts

This is greatly simplified but in short, `$` is used only on the right-hand-side when you have an assignment (using `def`). It has to be the first character. It should refer to a JSON variable. `$` will refer to the `response` variable by default, for example:

```
* def response = { foo: 'bar' }
* def temp = $.foo
* match temp == 'bar'
```